# Boxplot labelling outliers returns an error using data rownames

Tags: r, outliers

I am trying to label the outliers in my boxplot using the text function so I can find out from which class the outliers are coming from. I've stored the rownames of my data in variable "rownames" using names(vehData) to get the row names. When I apply this however, I get an error.

ERROR: **Error in which(removeOutliers1 == bxpdat$out, arr.ind = TRUE) :
'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'double'**

Completely new to R programming. Completely not sure how to fix this or what I am doing wrong
Thanks in advance for any help!

```
library(reshape2)
vehData <-
  structure(
    list(
      Samples = 1:6,
      Comp = c(95L, 91L, 104L, 93L, 85L,
               107L),
      Circ = c(48L, 41L, 50L, 41L, 44L, 57L),
      D.Circ = c(83L,
                 84L, 106L, 82L, 70L, 106L),
      Rad.Ra = c(178L, 141L, 209L, 159L,
                 205L, 172L),
      Pr.Axis.Ra = c(72L, 57L, 66L, 63L, 103L, 50L),
      Max.L.Ra = c(10L,
                   9L, 10L, 9L, 52L, 6L),
      Scat.Ra = c(162L, 149L, 207L, 144L, 149L,
                  255L),
      Elong = c(42L, 45L, 32L, 46L, 45L, 26L),
      Pr.Axis.Rect = c(20L,
                       19L, 23L, 19L, 19L, 28L),
      Max.L.Rect = c(159L, 143L, 158L, 143L,
                     144L, 169L),
      Sc.Var.Maxis = c(176L, 170L, 223L, 160L, 241L, 280L),
      Sc.Var.maxis = c(379L, 330L, 635L, 309L, 325L, 957L),
      Ra.Gyr = c(184L,
                 158L, 220L, 127L, 188L, 264L),
      Skew.Maxis = c(70L, 72L, 73L,
                     63L, 127L, 85L),
      Skew.maxis = c(6L, 9L, 14L, 6L, 9L, 5L),
      Kurt.maxis = c(16L,
                     14L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 9L),
      Kurt.Maxis = c(187L, 189L, 188L, 199L,
                     180L, 181L),
      Holl.Ra = c(197L, 199L, 196L, 207L, 183L, 183L),
      Class = c("van", "van", "saab", "van", "bus", "bus")
    ),
    row.names = c(NA,
                  6L), class = "data.frame")

#Remove outliers 
removeOutliers <- function(data) {
  OutVals <- boxplot(data)$out
  remOutliers <- sapply(data, function(x) x[!x %in% OutVals])
  return (remOutliers)
}

vehDataRemove1 <- vehData[, -1]
vehDataRemove2 <- vehDataRemove1[,-19]
vehData <- vehDataRemove2
vehClass <- vehData$Class

rownames <- names(vehData) #column names

#Begin removing outliers

removeOutliers1 <- removeOutliers(vehData)
bxpdat <- boxplot(removeOutliers1)

#Also tried using vehicles$Class instead of rownames but get the same error
text(bxpdat$group, bxpdat$out, 
     rownames[which(removeOutliers1 == bxpdat$out, arr.ind = TRUE)[,1]],
     pos = 4)
```

The boxplot looks like this. I am trying to label the outliers based on the x axis e.g. "Comp", "Circ", "D.Circ", "Rad.Ra", "Max.L.Ra" etc.. & by vehicle class "Van", "Bus" ..
[image]

Crammed text issue when identifying class

[image]

Comment: what are you trying to annotate? I can see that you have the outlier points from the 2nd boxplot, what are the supposed labels for these points?

Comment: The outliers within my data. Need to find out which class they belong to :)

Comment: you mean which column in ```vehData``` ? for example "Sc.Var.Maxis" ?

Comment: Yes, exactly!! I will edit the question

Answer (score 2):

If it is the outliers in the 2nd boxplot, it would be:

```
bxpdat <- boxplot(removeOutliers1)

text(bxpdat$group, bxpdat$out, 
     bxpdat$names[bxpdat$group],
     pos = 4)
```

[image]

Maybe looks better like this, if you adjust the margin and flip the labels:

```
par(mar=c(8,3.5,3.5,3.5))
bxpdat = boxplot(removeOutliers1,las=2,cex=0.5)
text(bxpdat$group, bxpdat$out, 
         bxpdat$names[bxpdat$group],
         pos = 4,cex=0.5)
```

[image]

Comment: Would it also be possible to see from which class they came from e.g. Van, Bus etc?

Answer (score 1):

I understood the question differently to @StupidWolf. I thought the goal was to replace points indicating outliers with the text of the vehicle class (bus, van or saab). If you simply print the variable name (e.g. Skew.maxis), then you might as well have simply plotted the outliers as points. Unless I'm missing something.

Here is code to answer the question as I understood it, for what it's worth (beginning after defining `removeOutliers`):

```
# CHANGE: Create vehClass vector before removing Class from the dataframe
vehClass <- vehData$Class

vehDataRemove1 <- vehData[, -1]
vehDataRemove2 <- vehDataRemove1[,-19]
vehData <- vehDataRemove2


#Begin removing outliers

removeOutliers1 <- removeOutliers(vehData)
bxpdat <- boxplot(removeOutliers1) # use boxplot(vehData) if you plot all the outliers as points

# loop over columns
n_plot <- 1; set.seed(123) # only plot n_plot randomly-chosen outliers 
for(i in 1:ncol(vehData)){
  
  # find out which row indices were removed as outliers
  diffInd <- which(vehData[[i]] %in%  setdiff(vehData[[i]], removeOutliers1[[i]]))
  # if none were, then don't add any outlier text
  if(length(diffInd) == 0) next
  print(i)
  print(paste0("l:", length(diffInd)))
  
  if(length(diffInd) > n_plot){
    diffIndPlot <- sample(diffInd, n_plot, replace = FALSE)
  } else diffIndPlot <- diffInd
  
  text(x = i, y = vehData[[i]][diffIndPlot], 
       labels = paste0(vehClass[diffIndPlot], ": ", vehData[[i]][diffIndPlot]))
}
```

Comment: Note that you can't label them using rownames of vehData, as you can't use rownames that aren't unique.

Comment: Thanks for this, I really needed this too! When I apply this  to my full dataset, my graph starts getting large black blobs due to text being repeated over each other in one area. Is there a way to fix this? I can't see the text at all thus not find the class the outlier belongs to. I have added an image to the post. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Would you recommend putting this into a data.frame somehow to see outliers and the class they belong to instead of showing it in a boxplot?

Comment: Well, if you have tons of outliers and you want to know how many per category belong to each class, then I'd probably do a table rather than plot it. A plot will just become messy if you label each individual outlier, as you've seen. 
Note that I've edited my code so that you choose to plot a randomly-chosen subset of outliers (using the `n_plot` variable). That will at least help give an idea of the typical class of the outliers. But I think, honestly, you'll struggle with many more than one or two outliers' classes plotted, as for example Skew.maxis is squished right onto the x-axis.

Comment: It seems like the variables are all on different scales, so you could consider centring and standardising them ((x - mean(x))/sd(x), perhaps using the `scale` function), and then plotting. That'll help make sure each column has vertical space.

Comment: It sounds like your focus is on the outliers, so yes, a table would probably be better. No point plotting all the data if you only want to know the properties of a few (that would be displayed poorly in a plot anyway).

Comment: Thanks for getting back. I am trying to see the outliers which are being removed and the class they belonged to. I was going to apply scaling after removing, I was told you should scale after removing the outliers, is this okay? I am not sure how to go about trying to show the outliers and their class in a table. Would you mind helping me with this? Thanks so much again!

Comment: Would you mind adding also the code to just display labels on the boxplot before you changed it plot randomly chosen ones?

Comment: Apparently long discussions in the comments are discouraged, so briefly:
- Identify the class of each outlier for each variable, and then use `table`. 
- To scale without letting outliers influence the scaling, use the function `scale2 <- function(x) (x - mean(x, trim = 0.2))/sd(x[x >= quantile(x, 0.05) & x <= quantile(x, 0.95)])`.

Comment: Thanks again! I will try this!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229741/discussion-between-ash-and-m-rodo).